# SQL - IF EXISTS UPDATE ELSE INSERT Syntax Error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM component_psar WHERE tbl_id = '2' AND row_nr = '1') 
   UPDATE component_psar
      SET col_1 = '1', col_2 = '1', col_3 = '1', col_4 = '1', col_5 = '1',
                 col_6 = '1', unit = '1', add_info = '1', fsar_lock = '1' 
    WHERE tbl_id = '2' AND row_nr = '1' 
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO component_psar (tbl_id, row_nr, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4,
                                col_5, col_6, unit, add_info, fsar_lock)
    VALUES ('2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'N')
```

Ignore the fact that I'm trying to set every column to '1'. It's just example data. :)

Anyways, executing this query returns a syntax error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
     MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM
     component_psar WHERE tbl_id = '2' AND row_nr = '1') UP' at line 1
```

I've been staring at it and searching the internet for a good half an hour and just can't find this supposed syntax error. It's probably going to end up being something really dumb that I'm missing but I could use you guys' help on this one.

Comment: Are you executing this in a stored procedure?

Comment: No, I'm not executing it as a stored procedure. Should I be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

Comment: The IF ESISTS syntax works only in MSSQL, not in MySQL.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO component_psar (tbl_id, row_nr, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, unit, add_info, fsar_lock)
VALUES('2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'N')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_1 = VALUES(col_1), col_2 = VALUES(col_2), col_3 = VALUES(col_3), col_4 = VALUES(col_4), col_5 = VALUES(col_5), col_6 = VALUES(col_6), unit = VALUES(unit), add_info = VALUES(add_info), fsar_lock = VALUES(fsar_lock)
```

Would work with `tbl_id` and `row_nr` having `UNIQUE` key.

This is the method DocJonas linked to with an example.

Comment: This worked great, thanks. I had to make tbl_id and row_nr a UNIQUE key for it to work but in hindsight they should have been unique anyway so that's just another thing done right. :)

Comment: Good to point out that `UNIQUE` columns act the same way as `PRIMARY`. I was unsure whether it would cause issues or not.

Comment: how do you know it was an insert or an update for later on operations?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html `With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated. `

Comment: I had trouble with inserting and updating a large table (150-200k rows), insert with update on duplicate was a lot faster. (5secs / 1000 rows vs 60secs / 1000rows)

Comment: It works when two of "tbl_id"  and "row_nr" if exists other wise insert is not working

Answer (score 13):

Here is the link to documentation [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) Statement.

Comment: I appreciate the sentiment (and your answer to begin with), but showing me an example of how to set a fire like Robin Castlin did is more useful than telling me to search for 'how to make a fire' on Google. :)

Comment: Although that's true, I for one learn best by examples. Hopefully this is enough for him to know how to use the function in the future.

Answer (score 5):

You have to add `THEN`

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM component_psar WHERE tbl_id = '2' AND row_nr = '1') 
THEN
UPDATE component_psar SET col_1 = '1', col_2 = '1', col_3 = '1', col_4 = '1', col_5 = '1', col_6 = '1', unit = '1', add_info = '1', fsar_lock = '1' WHERE tbl_id = '2' AND row_nr = '1' 
ELSE 
INSERT INTO component_psar (tbl_id, row_nr, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, unit, add_info, fsar_lock) VALUES('2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'N')
```

Comment: Is there an alternate for mysql?

Answer (score 3):

In this approach only one statement is executed when the UPDATE is successful.

```
-- For each row in source
BEGIN TRAN    

UPDATE target
SET <target_columns> = <source_values>
WHERE <target_expression>

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
   INSERT target (<target_columns>)
VALUES (<source_values>)

COMMIT
```

Comment: I'm going to use this rather than the accepted answer since in my application, I anticipate UPDATE will succeed the vast majority of the time.

Comment: actually, why not use merge statement? merge allows merging a source table into a target table and doing update, insert, and delete where necessary all in one pass.

Answer (score 1):

Isn't this maybe the most elegant?

```
REPLACE 
INTO component_psar (tbl_id, row_nr, col_1, col_2, col_3, col_4, col_5, col_6, unit, add_info, fsar_lock) 
VALUES('2', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', 'N')
```

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replace.html

Comment: Can I use multiple values on this? like with:
`INSERT INTO table VALUES (1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6)` and so on..?

Comment: It depends if you want to preserve the primary key/auto increment field. REPLACE will delete the original row if it currently exists before inserting. Also note that if you have a large number of records with indexes, then the deletes can take a long time and in this case are unnecessary if the record already exists.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following Statement:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM prueba )
then
  UPDATE prueba
  SET nombre = '1', apellido = '1' 
  WHERE cedula = 'ct'
ELSE 
  INSERT INTO prueba (cedula, nombre, apellido)
  VALUES ('ct', 'ct', 'ct');
```