# Inserting data in MYSQL table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have same title of products from different stores..lets say... Produt title=  A from store= 1 product title = A from store = 2... If  store= 1and s title=A  only udate price..if store =2 and product =A insert as a new row.. (shouldnt give error of duplications because its from other store).. And if title isnt duplicate simply. Insert it

How to do this with insert query in MYSQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BEGIN TRAN

UPDATE tablename
SET price = yourprice
WHERE store = 1 and title = A

IF (@@ROWCOUNT = 0)
   INSERT tablename (title, store, price, productid)
VALUES (yourtitle, yourstore, yourprice, yourproductid)

COMMIT
```

I am unable to test the code, but I copied it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639407/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert-syntax-error). Let me know if it helps.

Comment: If title is duplicate(same) store is different insert as a new row? And update if title is same store is same? And insert it simply if title isnt duplicate? How to do this

Comment: i did not get your comment. Can you explain? Also, why dont you look into  _if exists then update else insert_ quesries in mysql ?

Comment: I have same title of products from different stores..lets say... Produt title=  A from store= 1 product title = A from store = 2... If  store= 1and s title=A  only udate price..if store =2 and product =A insert as a new row.. (shouldnt give error of duplications because its from other store).. And if title isnt duplicate simly. Insert it

Comment: i updated my answer. hope it helps.