# if id exist use on duplicate key, else insert

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database with following table `test_users`:

```
| id | Username | Password |
|  1 |    pat   |  *****   |
|  2 |   roger  |  *****   |
|  3 |  luke93  |  *****   |
```

And to insert a new row I use following code, and it works fine:

```
$sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_users` (`Username`, `Password`) VALUES (?,?)");
$sql->bind_param('ss',$name, $email);
```

But now i am trying to make a "update profile"-page and I wanted to use ON DUPLICATE KEY. That means I need to check if `id`exists and if so update the row. Neither `Username` or `Password` is Unique, but `id` is. I have a $_SESSION["id"] which is available if the user is logged in. Can I use that in some way? 
So how do I write a SQL-sentence that finds out if `id` exist, and if so, overwrite it with ON DUPLICATE KEY (or a better way)?

Comment: Try if exists() function. Use the below link [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12639407/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert-syntax-error)

Comment: Assign unique key of your unique field and try below query
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists

Comment: check - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first write selct query and count num rows if its 0 then insert query fire else update query

Comment: I considered that, but hoped there was a solution for it with ON DUPLICATE KEY. But that is not possible?

Comment: when u inserting if filed autoincrement primary then how you get id?

Comment: You get your Id when you are logged in. It is saved in a session. If you are not logged in, you will not have a session with your id

Comment: INSERT INTO test_user(id, username, password) VALUES($_SESSION['id'], "test", "test") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    

username="test", password="test"

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE works the same as an insert. You just need to pass the WHERE condition.
You can do this with the following code, Try it

```
$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$sql = "UPDATE test_users SET Username=?, Password=? WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bind_param($Username, $Password, $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Yes, I know, that was the best solution I found, but I was hoping some people here knew a better way around this.

Comment: I don't think so that there is other solution than 'ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE'

Comment: @William82 what issues you are getting and how you are using it ?? show me your code so that I can help you.. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assign unique key of your unique field and try below query
[Insert into a MySQL table or update if exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4205181/insert-into-a-mysql-table-or-update-if-exists)

```
INSERT INTO test_user(id, username, password) VALUES(1, "test", "test") ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    

username="test", password="test"
```

Comment: but with that one I always will update row['id'] = 1, right?

Comment: @William82  you can made id dynamic, this is just example

Comment: so how can I make it dynamic and auto increment?

Comment: @William82 select auto increment option in database, then after don't insert id on insert time,

Answer (score 0):

Use INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

**QUERY:**

```
INSERT INTO table (id, name, age) VALUES(1, "A", 19) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE    
name="A", age=19
```

*credits to Donnie*

Comment: how does this work. It says value 1 in Id. Will it not update only where Id is 1? And if it is dynamic, what variable should I then use?